# How to get ul li elements float to down

Tags: html, css, display

[image: Look this image]

As usual ul li elements goes left to right as in red image. But i want the green image sequence. i used float and display inline block.. Please suggest

Comment: CSS `column-count` property.

Comment: If you want a modern approach, you can and should(!) use flexbox.

If do some research on it you will see that centering horizontally and vertically are easy.  http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `column-count` property **check the demo below**

```css
ul {
   -moz-column-count: 3;
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
   column-count: 3;
   column-gap: 10px 10px 0 10px;
   width: 450px;
   background: #3FB441;
   padding:10px;
}
ul li {
   line-height: 2em;
   display: block;
   background:#fff;
   text-align:center;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `column-count: 1;`. in CSS.

here is full details in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS-Property `column-count` to solve your problem.

```
ul#css3columnlist {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}
ul#css3columnlist li{
    line-height: 2em;
    display: block;
}
```

See this [website](http://www.css3.de/ul-liste-in-spalten-mit-column-count.html)